# select data on base of comparing multiple values between two columns in same table

Tags: php, sql, cakephp-3.0

[image]

question id (1,3,2,3)
responses id(1,6,4,7)

```
Question_Id   Response_Id
           1 =>1
           3=>6
           2=>4
           3=>7
```

I need to select those distinct users from users_response(following) table who answered all questions mentioned above and have the same answer as mentioned under response_id (1,6,4,7) to the question_id(1,3,2,3) respectively.

Result should be only '2'.

Can you please help me or give me some hint to deal with it. Any dynamic way because count of question_id and response_id can be increased. like in this example here are only total 4 conditions are given but it could go up or down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users_responses WHERE Question_Id = 1 AND Question_Id = 3 AND Question_Id = 2 AND Question_Id = 3 AND ( Question_Id = 1 AND Response_Id = 1 ) OR ( Question_Id = 3 AND Response_Id = 6 AND Response_Id = 7 ) OR ( Question_Id = 2 AND Response_Id = 4 ) GROUP BY user_id;
```

this will be your query if there are only 4, if there are multiple you could create an array with pair of Question_Id and Response_Id. loop through this array to create a where condition, store it in variable and pass in query.

Comment: this is using "OR" so any row who satisfy even single condition comes in the result. I tried with "AND" no row selected while there was a row with user_id 2 satisfying condition.

Comment: i have updated the query in answer try this one @coder

Comment: still getting wrong result (2,6) while the result should be only 2 , this query has "OR" which gives wrong output but without using "OR" zero result.  @parth

Comment: it needs to be OR, first 4 condition check if user have answered all question and other 3 condition in group check if any anser is right or not @coder

Comment: but I'm getting all users even who have not answered those all question or have not same answer

Comment: sure, i will upload it and share link with you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127919/discussion-between-coder-and-parth-mahida).